# Css not added to content loaded dynamic in IE

Tags: html, css, ajax, internet-explorer, dynamic

I have ben looking everywhere but I cant seem to find any good answer to this question.

I am loading a few items, first when page loads and then if the user wants to change language for example the divs are loaded dynamically again. In all browsers except IE this works fine. In IE the content is loaded BUT its css is completely lost. WHY? No clue? I have ben trying to load the css with the file I am loading without any result so now I am hoping for you guys!!
Please help

Comment: Can you post any code or a link to your page with jsfiddle?

Comment: Its on localhost for the moment. Its just simple jquery load that loads content from an external jsp file depending on what language is chosen.

Comment: Well maybe you could copy the code and paste it in your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Like the above comments said, we'd need to see the code to get a better perspective of what's happening.

Just a thought.  Have you gone through the debugging process with Console, this giving more information you could relay?  Does the CSS work before the user changes?  Is the CSS loaded in the header?  And/or for debugging purposes have you seen if inline CSS works?  (this would be better as a comment but I don't have that privilege yet).  Good luck, and let us know.